# IPython parallel computing on Windows PCs?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

can someone provide an answer if it is possible to use IPython for parallel computing on Windows PCs, and if so how should connections be made?

I watched on-line courses, and they were helpful but nothing about how to actually connect available PCs. I also did search but can't find definitive answer if it's possible on Windows or only on Unix like PCs

Thanks

Comment: [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) the shell?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about IPython and SciPy - using ipcluster and IPython MultiEngineClient. Everywhere I looked it's assumed that PCs are set and FURLs are present

Comment: Are you asking about tying multiple PCs together with IPython for parallel computing? If so, are these machines on the local network? Otherwise, are you talking about a single PC with multiple multi-engine client processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPython cluster mode seems to be [untested on Windows](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/parallel/parallel_process.html), you are literally on the bleeding edge there. Please test and improve iPython, the shell part of it is one of my best loved portions of Python.

That being said you have another much simpler to deploy parallel processing option for windows/linux/mac hybrid environments - [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/). It can do both multiprocesser and cluster modes. To use it simply install the pp module and start up ppserver from python_home/Scripts. This pickles methods and data and passes them around ppserver instances for computation. Pure python code can be very easily parallelized. Those using natives and other libraries will require the libraries to be preinstalled on all of the cluster nodes.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I thought that it's not supported on Windows as I read "somewhere", and I also posted on IP mailing list without success. My intentions are to use IP shell possibilities, thou thanks for pp module link, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python can be used for parallel computing on Windows too. Use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.